# VersionedRoute Attribute Implementation for MVC6

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, api-versioning

I am trying to enable versioning on a REST API, where the version is specified in the header, as `"api-version":2`.

According to [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-2-attribute-routing-with-custom-constraints) I just need to create

`VersionConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint`

and

`VersionedRoute: RouteFactoryAttribute`

The usage would be to apply the `[VersionedRoute("api/controllerName", 2)]` Attribute to Controllers, which are designed for specific versions (e.g. version 2 in this case).

This is all good and well, but unfortunately, it's all in MVC5 and I'm using MVC6. Therefore, `RouteFactoryAttribute` and `IHttpRouteConstraint` don't work.

I managed to find `IRouteConstraint` to replace `IHttpRouteConstraint` (hoping it will work), but I cannot find a replacement for `RouteFactoryAttribute`.

If anyone can provide a sample of this using MVC 6, or at least mention the correct classes (ideally with namespaces) I need to inherit from?

Comment: Thanks, I already looked at that code and it seems unnecessarily too much. Looking at old examples, there should be a more compact way to do this.

Comment: Since this is a new framework, there might not be a one-to-one mapping between apis. Sure you can try find out if there is a simpler approach with the new api.

Comment: @Bilo_ZA were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: I have updated my solution and I think it fits the bill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the minimum amount of work you need.

First, go [there](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/6.0.0-rc1/test/WebSites/VersioningWebSite) and copy the code for the 3 following files:

- [`VersionGetAttribute`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Mvc/6.0.0-rc1/test/WebSites/VersioningWebSite/VersionGetAttribute.cs)
- [`VersionRangeValidator`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Mvc/6.0.0-rc1/test/WebSites/VersioningWebSite/VersionRangeValidator.cs)
- [`VersionRoute.cs`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Mvc/6.0.0-rc1/test/WebSites/VersioningWebSite/VersionRoute.cs)

Once you have this, we'll change the `GetVersion` method of `VersionRangeValidator` for the following:

```cs
public static string GetVersion(HttpRequest request)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Headers["api-version"]))
        return request.Headers["api-version"];

    return "1";
}
```

That will read the header and return the API version. The default will be `v1` in this scenario.

Here's how to use it on controllers (or it can be the same controllers with 2 actions:

```
[Route("api/data")]
public class DataController 
{
    [VersionGet("", versionRange: "[1]")]
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "v1 data";
    }
}

[Route("api/data")]
public class DataV2Controller 
{
    [VersionGet("", versionRange: "[2]")]
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "v2 data";
    }
}
```

So now you just need to give it the right header and it's good. This code has been tested with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({url: '/api/Data/', headers: { 'api-version': 1 }})
    .then(function(data){
            alert(data);
            });
    $.ajax({url: '/api/Data/', headers: { 'api-version': 2 }})
    .then(function(data){
            alert(data);
            });
});
```

Comment: In your example you mention that the same controller can have 2 actions for different versions. I tested that and it works well but if the ```api-version``` does not match any, e.g: ```api-version: 3``` the routing will find an ambiguous route as there are 2 HttpGet Actions with same signature and it will throw an error: ```AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied```.
Any recommendation on how to handle that scenario? The parameter ```Order``` doesn't make any difference to set what action is preferred. Thx

Comment: You'll have to modify the code that was given in the sample but for me it would be about always providing a default handler. I sadly haven't tried that scenario and I will not be able to give you an answer before 2016. I currently don't have a VS2015 installed on this machine. :(

Comment: If my answer however matched your original question, please take the time to mark it as answered. :)

Comment: This is the valid answer. Unfortunately I'm not the user who created the question so I can't mark it as answered ;)

Comment: Lol Christmas insanity